# In Highcharts How to keep rectangle such SVG elements attached with series data but not with pixel when resize,reflow,redraw,zooming in out?

Tags: svg, highcharts, binding, axis, rectangles

You can see after i change browser's size,series data drawing could be auto resizing correspondingly well,but rectangle SVG element just keeps bond with pixels position in windows,

This is just ridiculous ,so now i must reassign this svg 's pixels values by toPixels function again and again in some resizing redrawing,zooming event handler and bla bla bla(not clear it will get how many scenarios to handle),

Is there any setting to let rectangle such SVG elements to bind with series data and x-axis index number but not with the pixels?

What i expect,no matter you resize,reflow,zoom in or out,the rectangle such SVG elements just go with x-axis index number and series data y. namely,auto re-positioning,auto resizing accompanying with  x-axis index number and series data y

I just can't understand why Highcharts SVG be designed like this,making things really trouble,it's really uncomfortable compared with some traditional plotting modules such as matplotlib.
Thanks!

[before resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2SxZ.jpg)

[not ok after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWp56.jpg)

[highcharts-area css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxqKm.png)

[highcharts-graph css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewda1.png)

[highcharts-tracker css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jVoD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is basically to make the red rectangle behave like a series (in terms of responsiveness).

Highcharts offers `polygon` type of series which would be a good solution for this case if rounded corners weren't your requirement (polygon doesn't support them).

It seems that appropriately styled `columnrange` series gets the job done (thanks to `borderRadius` property):

```
{
    groupPadding: false,
    pointPadding: 0,
    borderRadius: 10,
    showInLegend: false,
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 2,
    color: 'none',
    type: 'columnrange',
    pointRange: 4,
    data: [{
      x: 3,
      low: 1,
      high: 24,
    }]
```

`pointRange` works in both directions, so if it equals to `4` and `x` equals to `3` the column will span from 1 to 5. `groupPadding: false` and `pointPadding: 0` causes that rectangle represents exact values.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gd0v9Lop/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/s

Comment: thanks,buddy,though i already finished such trouble refitting work, i will give a try on your suggestion,that seems handy much more

Comment: Hi,Kamil, it seems your method gets another new issue,the ploygon always fills its area with color and no independently respective borderline with different color,if i set opaque to 0,it will just disappear,so opaque can't help,and i can't find fill-color similar parameter setting to set,too
what i expect is get a clear borderline of polygon and no fill inside the area of polygon,just keep it empty or completely opaque,the same effect with SVG do

Comment: You're right - Highcharts doesn't offer any option for styling the polygon's border. Simple CSS styling should solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hz1yn0aq/ You should also set `color` of the series to `'none'` (predefined in the library) or `rgba(192,192,192,0)`.

Comment: oh,it's awkward ,gets new issue again,setting color of series to be 'none' dose not works, you can see 3 new screenshots i added in the main post about the css analysis，it seem last one overwrite previous 2 on ' fill="none" ' setting,so area is still black...

Comment: it may related to my css involving issue , wii check again,is this right?:


    `<style lang="stylus" scoped>
       @import '~highcharts/css/highcharts.css'
       highcharts-area
           stroke red
       highcharts-tracker
           fill none
    </style>`

Comment: I don't use **styled mode** of Highcharts (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css) in the demo that I posted in my previous comment. Do you want to make it work in styled mode?

Comment: thing is like this:i'm just working in vue components and some its 3rd ui plugins environment, i tried  css  just as your way,but it make no any effect changing,so i then tried to involve css of higcharts as said above